# Sounds for your downloading pleasure - "Machines in a Bullet Factory"

Tags: sound-effects-recording, field-recording, download, library-sound-effects

Hey Everyone,

A while back I was on a shoot in a bullet factory, and had a bit of time between setups to run around in the production facility to record some of their machines...
I gave no idea what the machines are called, but the make some awesome sounds.
I used a Sennheiser 416 going through a Sound Devices 302 and into a Sound Devices 744T.
I trimmed the heads and tails of the clips, but otherwise performed no mastering or post of any kind.

[Get it here](http://soundcloud.com/kurt_human/sets/machines-in-a-bullet-factory)

Enjoy, have fun.

Comment: Unfortunately the set is now empty - probably because of capacity limitations on SoundCloud?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: I'm sitting here at midnight, listening to all your creepy SFX, after watching Scanners by David Cronenberg. My life is now complete, many thanks!